# sql how to add inner join and multiple conditions to filter

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join

I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT IP.IRId  
FROM cmp.NPTable NP
INNER JOIN IPTable IP ON IP.IPtId = NP.IPd
LEFT JOIN  IPCTable IPC ON IPC.IPId = NP.IPId  
WHERE NP.PCN Id = @PCNId  
     AND (IP.IsCompliant = 1 AND IPC.CheckId = 1) OR (IP.IsCompliant = 0 AND IPC.CheckId = 1)
```

This is not working correcty

THe IPTable either has IsCompliant = null, 0 or 1 -- this is basically to indicate true or false
IPC.CheckId is either 1 or 2 -- this is the primary ID in this table

The only match integer match is the value 1 between the two tables.

I only want to bring back rows if IsCompliant = 1 and CheckId = 1 
else if IsCompliant is null or 0, then CheckId = 2.

The clause I added to my where  which is
 AND (IP.IsCompliant = 1 AND IPC.CheckId = 1) OR (IP.IsCompliant = 0 AND IPC.CheckId = 1)

This does not work. Help. Will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There's no use of a `LEFT JOIN` here.  Your `WHERE` clause turns your `LEFT JOIN` into `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Hi. Left join returns inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Since you remove all null-extended left join rows in your where, your query doesn't make sense. Now: what rows do you want? You are not clear. You say "I only want to bring back rows [...]" but from what table/subquery?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE NP.PCN Id = @PCNId  
AND 
(
   (IP.IsCompliant = 1 AND IPC.CheckId = 1) OR 
  ((IP.IsCompliant is null or IP.IsCompliant = 0) AND IPC.CheckId = 2)
)
```